# Turn off scheduled Night Mode temporarily in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I have 'Night Mode' scheduled on my Windows 10 PC. Every day from 23:00 the night mode is being automatically enabled. Sometimes I want to turn it off for the current session without messing up my settings or having the need to reset my settings after I relog into my OS. I would like to have a shortcut for turning off the night mode for the current session, is there a way to do so? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

There's a "Night Light" button in the action/Charms sidebar that would let you quickly turn it on or off.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the ***Display*** settings and click on ***Night Light Settings***.

[image]

Click on ***Turn on now*** or ***Turn off now***, and this won't effect your scheduled night light settings.

[image]